# Able to access values on object but unable to access object in inside(undefined/null error)

Tags: javascript

I am using react. I am able to access values on object but unable to access object in inside(undefined/null error)
However the same thing is working in the console when I set window.specs to product.specs

Object -

```
const product = {
    _id: '1',
    name: 'blah',
    specs: {
        chip: 'H1-based',
        connectivity: 'Bluetooth 5.0',
    },
},
```

For example I am able to access values like _id, name but not specs

I am trying to access it using -

```
    <ListGroup.Item className="product__detail-row">
    {Object.entries(product.specs).map(([key, value]) => (
        <div>
            {key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substring(1)}: {value}
        </div>
    ))}
    <ListGroup.Item />
```

Comment: What code have you tried to access it?

Comment: Why are you storing data into the window object? Are you not using a data store like redux? or Reacts built in context?

Comment: I saved it into the window to access and debug it easily in the console. It works in the console but in the actual code create-react-app gives the null/undefined error

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.... finally after 4 hours. So what was happening is I was getting my data and setting the state in the 'componentDidUpdate' method which runs 10-20ms after the render method. So, during the first 'componentDidUpdate' 'product.specs' would be undefined. This caused react and create react app to freak out and give an error. So, all I had to do is add a conditional to check if it is defined

```
{product.specs &&
    Object.entries(product.specs).map(([key, value]) => (
        <p className="lead">
                                        {key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substring(1)}: {value}
                                    </p>
                                ))}
```

Comment: Please upvote I have put in so much effort

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing comma after the 'name' key

Comment: I made a typo while copying it however that is not the case in my app. Thanks for the effort

Comment: Oh my bad. Well depending on where you have declared your product, it could be **this.product.specs** instead